# Error in the hours when converting string to date using SimpleDateFormatter

Tags: java, simpledateformat

This is my code:

```
       String dateString ="Wed, 18 Dec 2013 17:40:55 EST";
       DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E,dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
       Date date=null;
       Timestamp timeStamp=null;
       try {
          date = (Date) formatter.parse(dateString);
          System.out.println("Date..."+date);
          timeStamp=new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
        //Handle Exception
       }
       System.out.println("timestamp..."+timeStamp);
```

This is my output.The hours are different.The timestamp is 3 hours lesser than the original date.Any help would be much appreciated.If its something to do with the timezone I used,may I please know the right timezone format.Thanks.

```
        Wed, 18 Dec 2013 17:40:55 EST
        Date...Wed Dec 18 14:40:55 PST 2013
        timestamp...2013-12-18 14:40:55.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested the code and it worked for me.

> Date...Wed Dec 18 17:40:55 EST 2013
>
> timestamp...2013-12-18 17:40:55.0

java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

look at the timezones ... EST -> PST differs by 3 hours. timezones are an attribute of a point in time. The specify how to read it in terms of humanly readable dates. The value since the epoch though is the same. So the written form is in EST. I am betting your system time is PST. I am betting the implementation of toString() for the timestamp does not print out the timezone if it is the same as the system timezone.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.There were only 3 timezone formats.Z,z,X.None of them matched EST.I tried all three of them

Comment: Has nothing to do with the format. Your code is completely correct :) It's just you are expecting the timezone to be maintained when it is parsed. It won't be. As soon as you use getTime() there is no more timezone information it's purely in millis since the epoch

Comment: Hey Greg,Thanks for the reply again.I am getting the dateString from a rss file.So is there anyway I can retain the exact time that I parse from rss file after converting to timestamp.

Comment: @Sher This should be the accepted answer, because it actually explains what's going on.

Comment: I wish I could have two accepted answers.The other one tried my code and found that it worked.:)